# I need a web hosting provider

Tags: mysql, php, hosting, web-hosting, providers

I have about 400 web sites to host and these sites are created by PHP+MySQL. I am looking for a cheap and good web hosting provider, any good idea?

(BTW, I am not going to use Dreamhost)

Comment: What's wrong with Dreamhost ?  Can you explain your criteria a bit more ?

Comment: I dont think Dreamhost's service is good. I had a bad experience with Dreamhost. They will block your service without any warnings and ...

Answer (score 1):

I use 1and1 for all 2 (two) of my HUGE webs sites, and it's cheap and beyond my expectations (of which I had little. :)

If it's your business then perhaps look for someone local, so you can go meet and develop a real relationship you'll be happy with in 5 years - even if they are a little more expensive right now.

In the end, I think this question may fall into the "subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion" categories that aren't allowed on serverfault. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would try [iPage](http://www.ipage.com/ipage/index.html). They have the most helpful support guys and I have never had any load issues even with a few forums I run on them. It will actually get you a month free to try them out.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a lot of success with [The Planet](http://www.theplanet.com/).  They offer a lot of options.  We have servers hosting sites for a little over a hundred clients, including offering them web based email for their domain.  Most of the management is done by Plesk.  We also have dedicated machines hosted by them.  They have usually gotten those machines up for us within a day.  Overall its been a good service and I've been happy with their service and management tools.  Also the price is a little better than some of the other providers.